# Why is Webstorm showing an impossible result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, webstorm, koa

Can anyone make sense of this apparent contradiction?

Please look at the following screen shot.

The debugger shows the correct error object but the roll over shows the parameter to be null. The latter appears to be the actual state because no error text gets logged to the log file but the debugger shows what should be there!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Please follow [WEB-13863](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13863) for updates